# Slide show in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to implement slide show in UIView with UIImageView. Is there any code to load image view at runtime using timer? If any one can please provide the code it will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animated the view using the code ...

UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

```
// load all the frames of our animation
campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-1.tiff"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-2.tiff"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-3.tiff"],
                                nil];

// all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
campFireView.animationDuration = 1.00;
// repeat the annimation forever
campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
// start animating
[campFireView startAnimating];
// add the animation view to the main window 
[self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this one:

NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"nature5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"nature6.png"] nil];
UIImageView *slidShowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
slidShowImageView.animationImages = imageArray; 
slidShowImageView.animationDuration = 0.25; 
 slidShowImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; 
[slidShowImageView startAnimating]; 
[self addSubview:slidShowImageView]; 
[slidShowImageView release];
```